# How to use our custom directive with x-editable

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I want to use some Custom directive in  editable-text

```
 <span  ui-Blur="testfn(price);" editable-text="entry.product_id" 
         e-name="product_id" e-style="width: 200px"  e-form="sentryform" 
         e-required> 
  </span>
```

I want to trigger some event on blur on the above text box I have written the directive for that which is working with normal text boxes but not with above shown "editable-text".

Answer (score 0):

x-editable has nice feature were all directives prefixed with an "e-" get appended to the actual edit control (with the "e-" striped of course). For example to add style in the input box you add:

```
e-style="color:red"
```

So adding:

`e-ui-Blur="testfn(price)"` on the span element you talk about, would result in that being added to the input dom element generated when entering edit mode.